# Is it possible to know which app is binding to my service?

Tags: android, android-service

When one app bind my service through [bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29), [onBind()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29) will be called.

My problem is that I want to know **which app** is connecting to my service. Package name, process id, or any infomation that keeps not changed while it is running about that app will be OK.

Is is possible? And how to?

And same problem appeared when one app call my service's interface defined in aidl file, can I figure out which app is calling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Binder` can call methods [like `getCallingUid()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#getCallingUid%28%29), then (if needed) cross-reference that information with things like `ActivityManager` and `PackageManager` to find out the likely package name of the caller.

I say "likely package name", because `android:sharedUserId` means that multiple apps can share one UID. That is unusual, but certainly not impossible.